# Image localization in uwp

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp, localization

```
<Image 
       x:Name="MeetingNoteSideButtonImg"
       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/AgendaPage/Notes.png" />
```

this works but I need to create a folder in AgendaPage folder as "en-US". I created it and now the image doesn't show up.

```
Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/AgendaPage/en-US/Notes.png"
```

I put the new source like this and now the image is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insure that you also "moved" the png to the new folder, and also that you have the proper "build option" in VS for the "moved" item. (Usually "Content").

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, you need to check the file properties.

1. Please check if `Notes.png` is in the folder `Assets/Images/AgendaPage/en-US`
   [image]
2. Please right-click `Notes.png` in Solution Explorer, select **Properties**.

   In the Properties window, check if the [Build Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022#build-action-values) is **Content**.

   [image]

Comment: I checked it all and still not working

Comment: Could you please provide a [example] to help us further check the problem for you?